# Unable to extract Recipients name in Outlook email Python

Tags: python-3.x, win32com

I am trying to extract recipients address and I get the following when I print it:

```
<COMObject <unknown>>
```

I have the following code. I have also tried `Receipient.Name`.

```
import win32com.client
import sys
import csv


outlook = win32com.client.Dispatch("Outlook.Application").GetNamespace("MAPI")
inbox = outlook.GetDefaultFolder(6)
messages = inbox.Items
message = messages.GetLast()
subject_list = []
sender_list = []
recipients_list = []
i = 0

while message:

    subject = message.Subject
    sender = message.SenderName
    recipients = message.Recipients


    subject_list.append(str(subject))
    sender_list.append(str(sender))
    recipients_list.append(recipients)
    i+=1

    message = messages.GetPrevious()
    if i > 10:
        break

for subject in subject_list:
    print(subject)   
for sender in sender_list:
    print(sender)
for recipient in recipients_list:
    print(recipient)
```

How do I get the recipients name or email address?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think "message.Recipients" is getting you a [Recipient Collection](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.outlook.recipients.aspx), rather than a particular Recipient. You can get around this by adding the individual recipients from the collection to your list instead.

For getting the email address, you might need a little extra navigation if the Address gives you the addresses as Exchange Users, so you can use a function from the [Address Entry](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.outlook.addressentry.aspx) to retrieve it. (You can find out more about some of these Outlook objects by navigating the msdn documentation in these links.)

I added a few lines to your code, and the following worked for me.

```
while message:

    subject = message.Subject
    sender = message.SenderName
    recipients = message.Recipients

    subject_list.append(str(subject))
    sender_list.append(str(sender))
    #This loop will add each recipient from an email's Recipients Collection to your list individually
    for r in recipients:
        recipients_list.append(r)
    i+=1

    message = messages.GetPrevious()
    if i > 10:
        break

for subject in subject_list:
    print(subject)
for sender in sender_list:
    print(sender)
for recipient in recipients_list:
    #Now that the for loop has gone into the Recipient Collection, this should print the recipient name
    print(recipient)
    #This is the "Address", but for me they all appeared as Exchange Users, rather than explicit email addresses.
    print(recipient.Address)
    #I used this code to get the actual addresses
    print(recipient.AddressEntry.GetExchangeUser().PrimarySmtpAddress)
```

Comment: I am getting an error: *recipients_list is not defined*

Comment: @Pankaj recipients_list is defined in the intial code from the question. It's initialized as an empty list: recipients_list = []

You should probably refer to the other variables set up in the code from the initial question